# PHP loading a view manually

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am deciding to have a little go at MVC without using a defined/commercial framework. I can handle creating models and controllers. The views are basic html in my case. The only thing I can't see a way of creating is when controller loads a view.

In codeigniter for example I would use this: `$this->load->view('view_name');`

but if I am creating this feature, how would it be?

p.s. any illustrating code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which feature is your question about? The `$this` ? The `load` ? The `view` ? Or the `->` ?

Comment: loading the view as whole. I could use include of course, but I don't think you can pass parameters to include() like you would with view()

Comment: `a defined/commercial framework`?? wel, you could do `this` or `that`. My point being, we can't help if you're not telling us which framework you're using.

Comment: @sys_debug , you are not talking about MVC views here. What you want is to know how to pass values to a [**template**](http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html).

Answer (score 1):

add function to your main controller like

appcontroler.php

```
function myLoadView($viewname){
    include $config['basepath'].'/views/'.$viewname.'.html';
}
```

like this you can implement

you can use like

`$this->myLoadView('index');`

UPDATED:-

update the function like this

```
  function myLoadView($viewname){
    include $config['basepath'].'/views/header.html';
    include $config['basepath'].'/views/'.$viewname.'.html';
    include $config['basepath'].'/views/footer.html';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because, if you are implementing some bizarre parody of MVC, that has been inspired by extensive use of Rails-like frameworks.

### View is not a template.

This is the part most of people cannot understand. Views are supposed to be instances, which are responsible for all of the presentation logic. They juggle multiple templates, choosing which to use, based on the data the pulled from model layer.

A *view* takes few of those templates, and combines them to create an HTML response, or instead of HTML, if it is required, it can just send an HTTP header.

### Where should the view come from

Controllers should not be "loading the view" or "creating the view". The view, fully formed, should be injected into controllers so that they can, in some occasions, change the state of that view.

Since in MVC-inspired patterns for web, it is quite common, that there is a 1:1 relation between controllers and views. You could just instantiate a view with same class name (just different namespace) approximately at the same stage when you crate instantiate the controller.

If you have the class name, you can instantiate the view before the corresponding controller. This way you can inject the view instance in the constructor of the controller.

Comment: «If you instantiate the view before the controller, you then can inject the view instance in the constructor of the controller.»

And start dealing with it (add Js, css, change content-type) from within the controller.

Comment: Na, I accidentally pressed enter.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would just have your controllers return a view. Many framworks do this. You could do return $this->view('your view class') or name it responseView('') etc. Then pass any variables as the second argument in an array so your view has access to it.

For example:

```
class SomeController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        // do stuff

        return $this->responseView('view_name', array(
            'param' => 'value',
            'title' => 'pages title'
        ));
    }
}
```

Then your front controller would test to see if it returned a view and if it did start handling the response.